# Is it possible to give the placeholder in bsdatepicker when we are using type="button" in a input

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

> Is it possible to give the placeholder in bsdatepicker when we are
>   using 
>       type="button" in a input

```
<input class="datepicker-input" #dp="bsDatepicker"
[bsConfig]="bsConfig"
[bsValue]="bsValue"
[container]="container"
[maxDate]="maxDate"
[minDate]="minDate"
[outsideClick]="outsideClick"
[isDisabled]="isDisabled"
[isOpen]="isOpen"
[triggers]="triggers"
[placement]="placement"
[placeholder]="placeholder"
type="button"
nbInput
(bsValueChange)="onValueChange()"
bsDatepicker>
```

Comment: None. But you can use value="Select date"

Comment: Test this on following link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Add extra attribute of value into input. It will automatically change after selection of Dates.

```
<input class="datepicker-input" #dp="bsDatepicker"

value="Select date" 

[bsConfig]="bsConfig"
[bsValue]="bsValue"
[container]="container"
[maxDate]="maxDate"
[minDate]="minDate"
[outsideClick]="outsideClick"
[isDisabled]="isDisabled"
[isOpen]="isOpen"
[triggers]="triggers"
[placement]="placement"
[placeholder]="placeholder"
type="button"
nbInput
(bsValueChange)="onValueChange()"
bsDatepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a placeholder when input type is **button**, but if you change type to **text**, you can add placeholder.

Please refer to this [stack-blitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-e8y7qn?file=app/app.component.html)